# knockoutjs 2.2.0 vs 2.2.1 and mapping 2.3.3 vs 2.4.0

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

With Knockoutjs 2.2.0 and mapping 2.3.3 this works.  With Knockout 2.2.1 and mapping 2.4.0 it does not.  Both were pulled using nuget, the older versions a while back in other projects.  I copied the files over into the same project.

I've tried the .debug.js as well for both versions, as well as mixing and matching versions.

Using the newer (2.2.1 and 2.4.0) the viewmodel values seems to be mapped just fine, it just doesn't update the markup with the value.

Did something change?  Am I using the wrong syntax?

Thanks!

Code shortened a bit.

```
function myObj() {

    var self = this;

    this.GetMyObj = function () {

        $.ajax({
            ....
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

            },
           ..
        });
    };


    this.ClaimID = ko.observable();
    ...

}
```

And then hooking it all up

```
   var vm = new myObj();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $(document).ready(function() {

        vm.GetMyObj();
     }
```

and of course the markup

```
<br/><br/>
    WORK!!!: <b><span data-bind="text: ClaimID"></span></b> stuff.
    <br/><br/>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle illustrating the issue?

Comment: can you at least post link to the documentation of mapping 2.4.0

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: I just noticed the mapping is 2.4.1 on the doc page.  Let me try that

Comment: no difference, let me see if i can figure out fiddle. =)

Comment: Anybody know of a cdn that has the mapping 2.4.0 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears the knockout 2.2.1 I was using was corrupted/messed up somehow.

I created a new project and linked it in from microsoft CDN instead of nuget and it works.

Sorry!